# Errors in backup database script when jumping many versions

Tags: sql-server

I have a script that takes a backup of a database.  This script works fine if I am going from version 1 to 2, but I receive errors about invalid columns if I go from version 1 to 15.  The columns are the same so I don't understand.

```
DECLARE @cVersion AS VARCHAR (128), @nHoursSinceLastBackup AS NUMERIC 
(16, 0), @SPID AS INT, @cConnection AS VARCHAR (256);

IF object_id('tempdb..#csrDBOldVersion') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #csrDBOldVersion;

CREATE TABLE #csrDBOldVersion (
    [version] VARCHAR (128),
    major     AS parsename(CONVERT (VARCHAR (32), [version]), 4),
    minor     AS parsename(CONVERT (VARCHAR (32), [version]), 3),
    build     AS parsename(CONVERT (VARCHAR (32), [version]), 2),
    revision  AS parsename(CONVERT (VARCHAR (32), [version]), 1)
);

IF object_id('dbo.metadata') IS NULL
    SET @cVersion = NULL;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @cVersion = (SELECT TOP (1) [version]
                         FROM   dbo.metadata);
        IF charindex('[', @cVersion) > 0
           AND charindex(']', @cVersion) > 0
            SET @cVersion = substring(@cVersion, charindex('[', 
@cVersion) + 1, charindex(']', @cVersion) - charindex('[', @cVersion) - 
1);
END
```

}

In checking 'select * from tempdb.sys.objects where name like '%csrDBOldVersion%'', the invalid column is not listed.  I'm not sure what the problem could be or where to start (maybe too many hours or incorrect format)?

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 255 Invalid column name 'DateProcessed'.

Comment: Where do you see the error -- what's the language of the script? "Line 255" would be of some help, if only you had the actual script/batch/stored procedure where that line occurs. That information is actually present in the error details if the client chose to log them (`SqlException.Procedure`, `SqlException.Errors`) -- but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: To me, this sounds like you added a field to a temp table, however, the old version was never droped and your drop logic is not being exercised, therefor the old table is still hanging around and errors when you attempt to access the new field.

Comment: Looks like it wasn't dropping, duh such an obvious one.  Thanks guys.  I'm apparently having a brain day, I will mark closed as soon as I figure out how to mark accepted answer.

Comment: I changed the comment to answer in case you would like to mark it as complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you added a field to a temp table, however, the old version was never dropped and your drop logic is not being exercised, therefore the old table is still hanging around and errors when you attempt to access the new field.